# Creating raw image from Widget or Canvas

Tags: flutter

My end goal is to be able to share a dynamic image by either passing the raw image data or saving the image to disk for a native android/ios service to share.  How would I convert a `Widget` or `Canvas` in flutter to raw image data (like `byte[]`)?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is support for this now. You can either use `RenderRepaintBoundry` or `OffsetLayer` or `Scene`. They all have a `toImage`. Here is the link to [RenderRepaintBoundry.toImage()](https://master-docs-flutter-io.firebaseapp.com/flutter/rendering/RenderRepaintBoundary/toImage.html)

```dart
class PngHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const PngHome({super.key});

  @override
  PngHomeState createState() => PngHomeState();
}

class PngHomeState extends State<PngHome> {
  GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();

  Future<void> _capturePng() async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = globalKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
    ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    Uint8List pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();
    print(pngBytes);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RepaintBoundary(
      key: globalKey,
      child: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: _capturePng,
          child: const Text('Take screenshot', textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is copied from [the docs](https://master-docs-flutter-io.firebaseapp.com/flutter/rendering/RenderRepaintBoundary/toImage.html) and adapted to latest null safety and dart language features. The values for `globalKey.currentContext` and `byteData` can be null, so your production code should ideally check them.

Comment: Great solution ! I'm wondering if it is possible to capture only parts of the Widgets ? Because only a portion of the widget is what I needed.

Comment: @colin If possible, try to wrap the part that you want to capture in one of the mentioned widgets. Also, [Scene.toImage()](https://master-docs-flutter-io.firebaseapp.com/flutter/dart-ui/Scene/toImage.html) receives a width and height, which you might be able to leverage differently (I'm not sure if it crops or distorts the original image):

Comment: > Gone through the paint phase

Does that mean the widget has to be on scree?

Comment: @lawonga I don't think the widget needs to be on the screen since you can also specify a pixel density to draw it at (not dependent on the actual device density)

Comment: I figured it out yesterday!! Thanks

Comment: is it possible to save canvas as jpg?

Comment: @aiki93 Not out of the box with this method. According to https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ImageByteFormat-class.html I see you have a choice between png and raw format (which I imagine is something like .bmp). If you really need jpeg you could consider converting to it later.

Comment: @AndreiTudorDiaconu - Capturing offscreen parts of the widget is important, I've opened a question about it here if you don't mind contributing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57583965/flutter-dart-capture-entire-partially-offscreen-widget-as-image

Comment: I cannot assign the result of findRenderObject to RenderRepaintBoundary as the type differs. 

"A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'RenderRepaintBoundary'."

Comment: @JPLauber Updated the answer to address your comment. I hope providing a broader context for the `_capturePng` method makes it clearer how it can be used. Also, the answer now uses null safety.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the **`Screenshot package`** to get an `image` of the `widget` you want.

https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot

Answer (score 6):

This is not currently possible from Dart code running in a FlutterView today, however we have a bug on file tracking implementing such: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6774

It is possible to render Flutter widgets as part of a FlutterView and then use Java or Objective-C interfaces onto the FlutterView to capture a picture, such as the standard android.View.getBitmap which FlutterView implements:
https://docs.flutter.io/javadoc/io/flutter/view/FlutterView.html#getBitmap--

If this important to your application needs and would like to be able to capture Bitmaps of Widget trees from inside Dart code we'd love to hear about it.  Please feel encouraged to provide further context on the above referenced issue!