# How would I go about making a bingo card in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've recently been trying to advance my knowledge in Flutter, and since there is a lockdown at the moment this is the perfect time. I'm wanting to do some image manipulation (i.e putting text and other images on top of eachother).. How would I go about making something like a bingo card? It seems a bit of a challenge since I'd have to make sure that the text doesn't flow out into other cells and overlap other text but please let me know if this is possible.

Cheers,
Jack

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Table` to accomplish this easily. Read more about it here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html

Comment: Thankyou! Is there any way to export this out into an image?

Comment: I haven't done this myself, but `Table` is just a widget, so any methods to export a Widget out to an image would work. Here are some references for this: https://medium.com/flutter-community/export-your-widget-to-image-with-flutter-dc7ecfa6bafb - and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957086/creating-raw-image-from-widget-or-canvas