# How to Convert a QrImageView widget into image in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-qrcode

I cannot figure out on how to convert a generated qr code by the use of QrImageView into a image file type that can be saved in the database

This is my code for generating a qr code:

```dart
Widget buildGenerateQrCode(){
    String qrData = '$docu_title, $docu_type, $docu_sender, $docu_recipient, $_selectedFile';
    return QrImageView(
        data: qrData,
        version: QrVersions.auto,
        size: 200.0,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`QrPainter`](https://pub.dev/documentation/qr_flutter/latest/qr_flutter/QrPainter-class.html) class of the `qr_flutter` package.

```dart
    ByteData qrBytes = await QrPainter(
      data: "http://www.google.com",
      topLeftRadius: 10,
      bottomLeftRadius: 10,
      topRightRadius: 10,
      bottomRightRadius: 10,
      gapless: true,
      version: QrVersions.auto,
      color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 118, 191, 1),
      emptyColor: Colors.white,
    ).toImageData(878);
```

You can do something with the image data, send it to database or save on disk.

Source: https://github.com/theyakka/qr.flutter/issues/115

Answer (score 0):

Convert any UI widget to Image without package
[Creating raw image from Widget or Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957086/creating-raw-image-from-widget-or-canvas)
and then save it local storage as file using `dart:io` and https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider